# How do I draw a curve of a function created by another function?

Tags: r

I want to draw the curve of function `f` generated by `fmaker`, the following way errs:

```
fmaker <- function(a) function(x) a*x   
curve(fmaker(2), 0, 10)

Error in curve(fmaker(2), 0, 10) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

but if I assign `fmaker(2)` to an variable `g`, it works:

```
g <- fmaker(2)
curve(g, 0, 10)
```

It appear strange to me because when using other functions like `lapply`, these won't make any difference:

```
lapply(list(1,2), g)
lapply(list(1,2), fmaker(2))
#both output correct answer
```

Could anybody tell me why? What's so special about `curve`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `curve` is using [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) on its first argument – rather than evaluating the expression, *then* passing it to `curve` as an argument, R passes the unevaluated expression to `curve`.

`curve` then attempts to evaluate the expression in its own context when it sees that the expression is a function call:

```
sexpr <- substitute(expr)
…
if (!((is.call(sexpr) || is.expression(sexpr)) && xname %in%
    all.vars(sexpr)))
    stop(gettextf("'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing '%s'",
        xname), domain = NA)
expr <- sexpr
```

Where `xname = 'x'`, and `all.var` is a function which returns all variables contained in an unevaluated expression.

This obviously fails (since `curve(2)` contains no `x`). Your second example succeeds because now you’re not passing a function call expression to `curve`, you’re passing it a single variable (referring to a function), so `curve` evaluates it by just calling it normally:

```
if (is.name(sexpr)) {
    expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edit) Note: this does not answer the OP question (function that returns function), but a more typical case.

You need to include 'x' in the function call:

fmaker <- function(x, a) a*x
curve(fmaker(x, a=2), 0, 10)

Comment: This is doing something different from what OP wants (namely, to use a function which returns a function), although it happens to work in this special case. It stops working as soon as `fmaker` is something more general.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right- I missed that point. Should I remove the answer?

Comment: No, leave it. This is still a valid approach in some situations.